# SQL Server Encryption and nhibernate

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, encryption, syntax

We have a database that has a few encrypted columns (symetric key as described [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/28/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-encryption-and-symmetric-key-encryption-tutorial-with-script/)). I'm trying to map these tables in a legacy app using using old-school NHybernate 2.1.2.4.

I thought I would be able to map the encrypted columns using a formula, like this:

```
<property name="Name" column="Name">
  <formula>
    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY MyKey DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE MyCert
    SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(150), DECRYPTBYKEY(Name)) AS Name FROM [Company] WHERE [Company].[Id] = Id
  </formula>
</property>
```

Unfortunately this does not work since I'm not allowed to use the open statement there.
I can reproduce the problem in pure SQL by trying this:

```
SELECT 
    Company.Id, 
      (OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY MyKey DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE MyCert 
      SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(150), DECRYPTBYKEY(Name)) FROM [Company] WHERE Id = Company.Id),
    Address
  FROM Company;
```

This gives the same error since Open does not return anything, it's a void statement.

Is there any way to get NHibernate to call Open somewhere else? Maybe just after opening a connection or in the session handling somewhere?

Otherwise, is there a valid SQL syntax to get that statement working inside a query?

Views, functions and stored procedures are not an option since they defeat the purpose of encrypted columns.

---- Edit ----

Doing the Open statement when the session is opened and putting this in the config:

```
<property name="Name" column="Name" formula="CONVERT(NVARCHAR(150), DECRYPTBYKEY(Name))" />
```

Seems to fix half of the problem, the field is read-only :-(

By the way, updating the field using plain SQL also gives crazy results. When I do this:

```
UPDATE Company 
  SET Name = ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('MyKey'), 'Hello World')
  WHERE Id=1000;
```

And then read it back using `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(150), DECRYPTBYKEY(Name))`, I get some interesting characters '效汬⁯潗汲d' back instead of 'Hello World'.

I guess upgrading our SQL2005 database and using TDE as [Remus Rusanu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105929/remus-rusanu) mentioned is the best option.

Comment: `ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('MyKey'), 'Hello World')` would have to be decrypted as `CONVERT(VARCHAR(150), DECRYPTBYKEY(Name))`. ANSI input must be cast to ANSI output (ie. `VARCHAR`). To output Unicode should hade encrypted Unicde, ie. `ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('MyKey'), N'Hello World')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the purpose of your encryption? By using a certificate encrypted by the database master key, as it appears to be the case, any user or application can decrypt the data. You are not providing cryptographic protection, you only offer access protection (grant/deny/revoke access to data and/or keys). Cryptographic protection would require your *user* to specify the password required to unlock the root of the key hierarchy. What you're doing has valid use (loss of media protection) but it can be handled 1 million times better by [Transparent Database Encryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx) or by [BitLocker](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/bitlocker).

As for your problem: just open the key in the session (ie. when you open the connection). There is zero reasons to try to open it on-demand on per-statement access.

Comment: It is indeed just for protecting backups and the physical database files. From my perspective quite useless but apparently not from a sales perspective. I guess just encrypting the backup files would be allot simpler. I also foresee more problems than benefits, for example when we need a backup to reproduce a live problem while debugging offline, or when doing acceptance test on upgrade migrations etc... but anyway, I'll try to find an entry point when opening a session. I'll also give TDE a look. I don't think BitLocker will help since the backups are stored remotely. Thanks.

Comment: TDE is an Enterprise feature, so this may disqualify it. But it does solve all the problems you mention. Strictly speaking the column level encryption (`DECRYPTBYKEY`) can (and likely will) leak unencrypted data in `tempdb` and this can end up on a discarded HDD at the flea market, which is something TDE would ensure does not happen.

Answer (score 1):

For decryption during read, you can use [DECRYPTBYKEYAUTOCERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/decryptbykeyautocert-transact-sql) in the formula- that performs decryption without having to specify OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY. Unfortunately, it being a formula field means it can only be used for reads. This [5-part blog series](https://brosteins.com/2014/07/19/sql-server-database-encryption-with-nhibernate-series-part-1-of-5/) goes into details of how to make this work for read and write, but I admit as does the author of the series - it is a bit hacky.